# Switching authentication provider

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, authentication, adfs, kerberos

Trying to switch from an ADFS Trusted Identity Provider to Kerberos. In the user profile service, users appear to be different identities. Do I need to migrate every account using Move-SPUser? It seems like most other migrations go from Kerberos to a trusted identity provider not the other way around

Comment: Are you going ntlm with kerberos from ADFS?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: Then yes you have to run the move spuser, check my reply

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes you have to migrate all users from ADFS to windows claims. As sharepoint treat both as a separate ids.

You can also witness after switching the authentication, your user will get access denied. 
Now you have to run the move spuser to move them.

[Read this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/db58e874-4e22-419f-b0cf-1bc6e7540245/ntlm-and-adfs-claim-treated-as-different-user?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

Answer (score 0):

Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity "http://XXX:8001/" -To Claims -RetainPermissions

I use the above command to convert website XXX on port 8001 to Claims mode.

A good Microsoft reference is:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2010/05/08/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works/

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect. They're asking about switching from Kerberos (which is probably using Windows Claims) to SAML. SAML conversion requires different switches as outlined in [Migration of Windows claims authentication to SAML-based claims authentication in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn744263.aspx). Here is a potentially useful additional KB: [The Convert-SPWebApplication command cannot convert from Windows claims to SAML in SharePoint Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3042604.)

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from SAML to Windows Claims requires some slightly different steps. Microsoft has outlined it here: [Migration of Windows claims authentication to SAML-based claims authentication in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn744263.aspx). Note that this article includes both processes (Windows -> SAML; SAML -> Windows).

You may also find this KB useful if you run into any issues with the conversion. [The Convert-SPWebApplication command cannot convert from Windows claims to SAML in SharePoint Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3042604).